# I am creating a procedure in MariaDB, but it is giving Error "#1064 "

Tags: sql, mariadb, procedure

I am creating a procedure for a split string in MariaDB but it is giving error

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRUNCATE TABLE `splittedstringtable`"

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE splitstring( IN splittedstring varchar(256))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS splittedstringtable (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID))

 TRUNCATE TABLE `splittedstringtable`

    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0
    DECLARE y INT DEFAULT 0 

    SET y = 1

    IF NOT splittedstring IS NULL 
    THEN 
           SELECT LENGTH(splittedstring) - LENGTH(REPLACE(splittedstring, ',', '')) INTO @noOfCommas

           IF  @noOfCommas = 0 
          THEN 
                 INSERT INTO splittedstringtable(NAME) VALUES(splittedstring) 
          ELSE 
                SET x = @noOfCommas + 1 
                WHILE y  <=  x DO 
                   SELECT split_string(splittedstring, ',', y) INTO @engName 
                   INSERT INTO splittedstringtable(NAME) VALUES(@engName)
                   SET  y = y + 1
                END WHILE
        END IF
    END IF
END
```

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB/MySQL statements are terminated with semicolons `;`. Add semicolon after each statement.

You might also want to reconsider to use temporary table instead of normal table as you might run into trouble when multiple users are running the procedure at same time.